# how to avoid twitter already authorized on the device using share kit in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sharekit

I used sharekit for twitter integration in my app. That works fine on the simulator. But on the device , for the first time it allows me to login into the twitter . Now i deleted the app from the device and create new build and deploy that into device again.  Now it shows already authorized for twitter , not able to login even i deploy the new build on the device

Any ideas..to avoid this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data for Sharekit's Twitter implementation are stored in the user's keychain when you run on the device. Because of this, deleting the app will not delete the token for Twitter stored in the keychain by Sharekit. When you delete and reinstall the app, it's still reading from the keychain and picking up the old credentials. You need to implement the logout functionality. The implementation is pretty simple. You just call

```
[SHKTwitter logout];
```

Check out the ShareKit [documentation](http://getsharekit.com/docs/#logout) for details and options.